# Create Azure alerts (not classic) by resource manager templates

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have created some of the new alerts through the portal UI and now need to deploy these by resource manager template, but I am unable to locate the JSON schema for this resource type.

I can find the resource listing in the relevant resource group in the Resource Explorer website (looks like it must be the type microsoft.insights/scheduledqueryrules), but the JSON to create the resource does not exist.

There is documentation for templating the classic alerts, but nothing for the new type.

Is it possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Resource Explorer in Azure Portal, not the https://resources.azure.com/ one as it seems to not include everything.

I wrote a blog about the whole process. It includes the ARM template and some common gotchas you might come across.

http://chapsas.com/setting-up-alerts-using-application-insights-the-new-ones/